# Do I need to close the datareader

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have this simple function that takes care of all the queries:

```
DataTable ReadIt(string query, params MySqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(sConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = query;
        foreach (var p in sqlParams)
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
        MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        dt.Load(myReader);
        myReader.Close();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Do I need to put `myReader.Close();` after loading the data to the datatable or does the reader closes automatically after `using` ?

Comment: What using? I see no using that contains the reader as resource.

Comment: @TomTom I think he means does it close automatically after the `using` block for the `MySqlConnection`

Comment: @Cornwell note that the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnect` is designed to close the Connection when the Reader is closed, not vice versa.  In general, it's a good idea to make sure you close/dispose of things when you're done with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't know (or at least you shouldn't know) what resources the DataReader is holding.
On the other side every disposable object should be disposed because, in the disposing code, the object has the opportunity to release, as soon as possible, the resources used.
So also your MySqlDataReader should follow the same pattern used for the MySqlConnection and also for the MySqlCommand. The Using Statement is your friend

```
using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(sConnection))
using(MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandText = query;
    foreach (var p in sqlParams)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
    using(MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        dt.Load(myReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I always close the data reader object. But this is a way better solution.

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable.Load` will automatically close the reader *if* there are no more result grids. That is a bit hit and miss for my liking; I'd use `using`:

```
using(var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) {
    dt.Load(myReader);
}
```